# OpenCL Optimization

Tags: opencl

Im new in OpenCL.
I wrote an OpenCL kernel to compute grayscale. How Can I optimize that code, is possible? Why the computational time is floating so much? Sometimes Im speedup others not. Im doing something wrong?

```
kernel code:
kernel void grayscale(__global unsigned char *input)
{
    size_t i = get_global_id(0);    

    float grayscaleValue = (input[i*3] * 0.299F) + (input[i*3+1] * 0.587F) + (input[i*3+2] * 0.114F);

    input[i*3] = grayscaleValue;
    input[i*3+1] = grayscaleValue;
    input[i*3+2] = grayscaleValue;   
}


cpu code:
void GrayScaleCPU(struct PPMFile *ppmStruct)
{    
    for (int i = 0; i < ppmStruct->imageSize; i+=3)
    {
        float greyscaleValue = (ppmStruct->data[i] * 0.299F) + (ppmStruct->data[i+1] * 0.587F) + (ppmStruct->data[i+2] * 0.114F);
        ppmStruct->out[i] = greyscaleValue;
        ppmStruct->out[i+1] = greyscaleValue;
        ppmStruct->out[i+2] = greyscaleValue;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    struct timespec tS1, tS2;

    tS1.tv_sec = 0;
    tS1.tv_nsec = 0;

    tS2.tv_sec = 0;
    tS2.tv_nsec = 0;

    ...

    clock_settime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tS1);
    GrayScaleCPU(ppmf);
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tS1);

    printf ("Timming took %.12lu seconds to run.\n", tS1.tv_nsec);

    ...

    clock_settime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tS2);
    GrayScaleOpenCL(ppmf2);
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tS2);

    printf ("Timming took %.12lu seconds to run.\n", tS2.tv_nsec);

    float time2 = tS2.tv_nsec;
    float time1 = tS1.tv_nsec;
    float speedup = time2/time1;

    printf ("Speed UP OpenCL/CPU %.20f.\n", speedup);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you measuring and how?

Comment: I'm measuring the time inside both functions. In case of opencl Im measuring all things concerning to prepare to lunch the kernel. Using struct timespec. It's right? @Jovasa

Comment: So you are measuring creating the commandqueue, context and bulding the program? If so you are doing it wrong, also you should measure the execution around ten times, discard the first because it's often slower and then take average.

Comment: Yes, Im measuring everything, dont should do in that way? I should only measure the execution of kernel "clEnqueueNDRangeKernel"? About the memory transfer between the devices should I discard too?

Comment: Memory transactions are fine to include but on modern GPU they happen parallel to calculation (the second iterations calculation can happen at the same time as the first iterations data is read back). But yes you should only measure the kernel execution time and data transfers check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980090/opencl-performance-measurement and there are some other question also that should help you

Comment: Thanks for you help!!! @Jovasa

Answer (score 1):

Try buffering your global memory into thread memory:

```
unsigned char l_input0 = input[i*3];
unsigned char l_input1 = input[i*3 + 1];
unsigned char l_input2 = input[i*3 + 2];
//compute grayscale using l_input0,1,2
input[i*3] = grayscale;
input[i*3 + 1] = grayscale;
input[i*3 + 2] = grayscale;
```

Also, if your data isn't spaced properly when you call your kernel, you may end up executing on each unsigned char, instead of every 3rd unsigned char as in your for loop example.

You can then go further using local memory and work groups and do your calculations in chunks, though that is more challenging as local work sizes are very device specific and need to be a multiple of the global work size. I've found local work sizes of 16, 32, and 64 work on most devices.

Finally, you benchmarking OpenCL, **make sure you are measuring kernel performance and not kernel enqueue time**. The easiest way to do this is to start a timer, enqueue you kernel, call clainish on the queue, then stop the timer. There are timing and profiling built into most OpenCL devices which are handled by the queue.

Comment: Why I shouldnt measure the enqueued time? It's belong to process, isnt? @Austin

Comment: Sure, you can measure it, but it is A) insignificant, and B) just because the kernel is enqueued does not mean it is finished, so be careful how your are collecting your timing data. That was the warning.